# Difference between EclipseLink and Hibernate for long running sessions (Vaadin 7 and JPAContainer)

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

Although I need this answer to better understand how I can integrate Vaadin 7 and the JPAContainer addon in Wildfly 8.1, this is a general question that applies to Hibernate and Eclipse-link JPA implementations.

JPACaontainer Vaadin Addon recommends to have an EntityManager for the whole servlet-session, this IMO is not good design because AFAIK (and please correct me) to scale it will always be better to use stateless EntityManager-Per-Request pattern

JPAContaner Addon states that:

1. Hibernate can not keep entity managers for long without problems.
2. One issue with Hibernate is that it is designed for short-lived sessions, but the lifetime of an entity manager is normally roughly that of a user session (read, servlet session). The problem is that if an error occurs in a session or an entity manager, the manager becomes unuseable. This causes big problems with long-lived sessions that would work fine with EclipseLink.

What is the difference between Hibernate and EclipseLink, at the implementation level that makes those two statements be true? OR, are those two statements sill valid in the first place?

Comment: The EntityManager API is used to access a database in a particular unit of work. (source : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/#d0e61) Em is designed to be short lived. It's very clear in the related JSR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only speak for Hibernate, so here are my thoughts:

- Hibernate supports [long-conversations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch13.html#transactions-basics-apptx) and you can choose to work with

  - "detached objects"
  - "extended Session" (a Hibernate Session that's disconnected from DB, yet it's not closed)

  The optimistic locking mechanism will prevent losing updates so the shorter the conversation the less chances of stale exceptions.

  If any constraint violation is being thrown the Session is indeed unusable which makes the "extended Session" more fragile than working with "detached entities".

  With detached objects you keep a reference to those entities you plan on managing throughout your conversation and only reattach them (or merge them) when the workflow is 
  over.
- According to [Hibernate Session docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html):

  > If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled
  >   back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session
  >   might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs.

  If the internal Session state can't be synchronized to the database any more (because of Constraint Violation Exceptions or Optimistic locking exceptions) the Session is no longer usable and you'll have to restart a new clean Session. Otherwise you keep on receiving the save exceptions as long as the current entities are stale or have invalid data.

  One alternative would be to clear the Session and discard all your current pending changes that end up throwing exceptions, or refresh the failing entities.

I wonder how EclipseLink manages to work in these scenarios, as a broken Session is not always recoverable, like when you have stale data and refreshing would mean "loosing updates".

Comment: I am more interested in the behaviour of hibernate as a JPA implementation. So, when you say "Session" can I read "EntityManager" or it's something different? Also, how do I _choose_ in standart JEE to use "detached objects" or "extended session" ?

Comment: A Hibernate Session is the same thing with the JPA's EntityManager. In standard JEE, an extended persistence context is usually implemented with [Stateful Session Beans](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/extended_persistence_context_in_stateful). Adam Bien's "Rethinking Best Practices" has a very good example of this pattern. For "detached objects" you just have to pass entities out of your service layer to the View layer and they become "detached", being no longer managed by the Persistence Context. The next request might resend the "detached entities" back to service.

Comment: Incredible useful answer. I learnt more of hibernate than I expected. Now it's just about the difference with EclipseLink. I'll wait a little maybe someone points out how eclipse link works. Thanks.